# Perl - Force LWP::Protocol subclass selection, or is there a better way?

Tags: perl, asynchronous, lwp-useragent, anyevent

**Background**:

I've written an [LWP::Protocol](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/Protocol.pm) "implementor" for HTTP(S) based on [AnyEvent::HTTP](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/AnyEvent-HTTP-2.15/HTTP.pm). (i.e: it implements *both* HTTP and HTTPS).

It's different than [LWP::Protocol::AnyEvent::http](http://search.cpan.org/~ikegami/LWP-Protocol-AnyEvent-http-v1.8.0/lib/LWP/Protocol/AnyEvent/http.pm) or [Coro::LWP](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/Coro-6.33/Coro/LWP.pm) in that it doesn't BLOCK on `$protocol->request`. I've implemented most of the same hacks for select(), name-resolution etc that [Coro::LWP](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/Coro-6.33/Coro/LWP.pm) does, but making better use of [AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/AnyEvent-7.07/lib/AnyEvent.pm).

The HTTP response returned by `$protocol->request()` is `230 - Pending Completion of Request` for now but I'm open to better ways to convey that it isn't a completed request.

I've also written a subclass of [HTTP::Response](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.06/lib/HTTP/Response.pm) which forces BLOCKING on the standard "consumer" methods if they attempt to use parts of the response before it's complete; it also adds methods for working nicely with internal/provided [AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/AnyEvent-7.07/lib/AnyEvent.pm)`::CondVar` so that you can fire lots of requests off at once, as well as do other stuff with [AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/AnyEvent-7.07/lib/AnyEvent.pm). (I've also overridden all of LWP::UserAgent's post-`send_request()` logic to defer it until the real request completion).

**Problem**:

I'm currently doing a hack were I have my [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) subclass "upgrade" the URL `scheme` by appending `'_async'` for async requests, and I've got the [LWP::Protocol](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/Protocol.pm) subclass being an "implementor" for schemes matching `/^https?_async$/`

**Question**:

How can I get my [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) subclass to choose my (*more* asynchronous) HTTP & HTTPS protocol "implementors" instead of others installed on the system? (i.e: when the [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) subclass calls [LWP::Protocol](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/Protocol.pm)`::create`).

Can I force selection of my "implementors"? Or is there a more natural way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `implementor` in close proximity to your `send_request` call:

```
LWP::Protocol::implementor('http', 'your::module::name');
```

See source of http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/LWP-Protocol-http10-6.03/lib/LWP/Protocol/http10.pm to understand what you need to implement to replace the HTTP protocol handler

Comment: As I said in my question it's both HTTP and HTTPS protocols I wish to override. `AnyEvent::HTTP` already deals fine with SSL. I'm trying to get `LWP::UserAgent` to use *my* LWP::Protocol "implementor" over others installed on the system (e.g: LWP::Protocol::http, LWP::Protocol::AnyEvent::http) that implement the same schemes - HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: If you actually read the question, I've written a subclass of LWP::UserAgent. LWP::UserAgent calls `$protocol->request` from the "appropriate" LWP::Protocol subclass (where $protocol is manufactured by a factory function called `LWP::Protocol::create`). My question is about how to influence that selection.

Comment: Ok, sorry, but your question isn't very clear to me, so now, have you tried to change the LWP::Protocol::implementor ? http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/Protocol.pm

Comment: Specifically  LWP::Protocol::implementor('http', 'your::module::name');

Comment: I've done that. It still chooses another implementor. There are several that implement 'http'.

Comment: So you are not calling it in the right order, or you are not using Your::CustomAgent and inside it call the implementator

Comment: Ok, so do I need to (e.g:) `use LWP::Protocol::http_async` before requiring LWP::UserAgent? Will that cause that particular implementor to be chosen?

Comment: It needs to be called before as far as I remember, as it will override an undefined value, but not a defined one, this is why the order is important

Comment: Or do I need to make sure `implementor` gets called just before `request`?

Comment: Try to dump the data structure of your LWP and see which implementor is defined

Comment: Ah, OK, so the catch is that LWP::Protocol::AnyEvent::http (an "http" implementor) is also loaded so that I can use it's `lwp_request2anyevent_request` method. If all it takes is to avoid doing that, and to manually `use use LWP::Protocol::http_async` then that'll be easy enough.

Comment: The one from `LWP::Protocol::AnyEvent::http` is defined. (As I mentioned just now, I use one of its methods).

Comment: That works. :-) If you edit your answer to remove all the SSL stuff, and mention that `implementor` needs to be called in close proximity to `LWP::UserAgent::send_request()`, then I'll accept your answer.